# is there a way to express "if and only if" in SMTLIB?

Tags: z3, smt

Is it the same as `define` in SMTLIB? Or is the only way to define a function on my own? If z3 has a way to do that via its python binding that would work for me also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In SMTLib, `iff` is simply `=` over booleans:

```
(declare-fun a () Bool)
(declare-fun b () Bool)
(assert (= a b))
```

In z3py, you can use the regular equality comparison:

```
from z3 import *

a, b = Bools('a b')

s = Solver()
s.add(a == b)
```